# Correctly configuring a Postgres DB for a Rails 4.2 app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm confused about how to configure the DB in a Rails 4.2 app that uses Postgres and Heroku.

Following the advice [in this Heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#write-your-app), you'll get a `config/database.yml` like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_name_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_name_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_name_production
```

But when I tried this, my development and test environment were using the same DB as the staging environment (note the file has no configuration for staging). That's no good.

This [Heroku guide for connecting to the DB in Ruby](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-ruby) mentions that any Rails apps *before 4.2* would have their `database.yml` file overwritten by Heroku. Heroku will parse the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable and create a new `database.yml` file.

So I guess it's possible to just leave out the configuration in `database.yml` for any environments that you have on Heroku, such as staging and production. Your [`database.yml` file could essentially look like Hound's](https://github.com/thoughtbot/hound/blob/fa64c04c90ec8da6d67dd7ea03b5a29dff6d0423/config/database.yml) (note the lack of a production configuration).

```
development: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_development
  pool: 5

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test
```

But since we're using Rails 4.2, I don't think Heroku will override the `database.yml` file. In that case, do you have to specify DB configuration in `database.yml` for our environments on Heroku? Or is it still safe to leave them out? If we do need to specify the configuration for Heroku environments, will the following be sufficient?

```
staging:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

I'm also confused about the proper configuration for the development and test environments. As I mentioned above, the first configuration shown has those environments using the staging DB on Heroku, instead of a local DB.

[This Heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup) says to export the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable for your app to connect (once Postgres is installed and you can connect to it).

Assuming you export the `DATABASE_URL` env var as specified in the article, what does your configuration for development and test have to look like? Do we go with the configuration as shown in the first guide, e.g.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_name_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_name_test
```

Or do we use a configuration as shown in [this Heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-ruby) (which uses `host` and `username`)

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  username: user
  database: app-dev
```

**Update 1:** Here's what I now know. A staging and production config isn't necessary in `config/database.yml` if you deploy to Heroku, no matter your Rails version. Prior to 4.2, Heroku would generate it's own `database.yml` file based on the value of the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable, overwriting your config file (if it exists). Since Rails 4.2, your app will use the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable directly (bypassing the `database.yml` file), so Heroku doesn't need to (and won't) generate a config file.

I also figured out why my development and test environments were using the remote staging DB from the Heroku app instead of the local DBs specified in their `database.yml` config. It was because my local `.env` file for development is based off of my staging `.env` file which contains environment variables for connecting to the database such as `DATABASE_URL`. Because `DATABASE_URL` was present in my development `.env` file, my Rails 4.2 app was using it and thus connecting to the staging DB. To fix it, I removed those environment variables from the development `.env` file and created the local DBs (and ran the migrations) with `bundle exec rake db:setup`.

**Update 2:** This section of the Rails Guides goes into more detail about how to configure the DB, worth a read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Answer (score 3):

Most of your assumptions are correct. The following is a reasonable `database.yml` configuration file.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_name_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_name_test

staging:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

Make sure that the `RAILS_ENV` is properly set on Heroku (either `staging` or `production`), or Rails will default to `development`.

Locally, the test will pick the `test` environment. By default, the app will start in development mode, using the `development` environment.

Comment: Simone, is it a good practice at the moment (same stack + Puma server) to put 'pool: <%= ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5 %>' to the production option? My database.yml is gitignored currently, but for threaded servers heroku suggests to set pool value to be the same as MAX_THREADS  in the database.yml file. I'm asking this question to make sure I don't do any stupid thing and because heroku's docs phrasing sounds contradictionary when it come to database.yml.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, many developers choose to **ignore** the `database.yml` in version control and never publish it into the repo. The reason for that is, that databases may be different on different machines, that's a reason not to keep the configuration common.

I'm working on a Rails 4.2 project right now, and Heroku has no problem with having no `database.yml` at all (both with PostgreSQL and MySQL, we tested both). Why? Because `DATABASE_URL` provides all the information necessary to access the database, **even adapter name**. How? Here's the formula:

```
adapter://username:password@hostname:port/database?options
```

Locally, I'm using Postgres with peer authentication: the database server assumes the same username that I'm using in my OS, `username` is covered, `password` is useless. Local machine is assumed when no `host` is given, although I can't tell if it tries to communicate via TCP/IP or Unix domain sockets, so I'm fine without `host`.

So the configuration you refer to as "shown in the first guide" is reasonable: it contains a minimum amount of settings and allows you to create more environments quite easily.

Comment: I recommend never using "staging" on Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-to-a-custom-rails-environment

Answer (score 2):

Heroku doesn't create a database.yml on rails 4.2 because as of that version rails will detect the presence of that environment variable and use it to configure the database connection.

Adding

```
production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

Makes it a little more obvious  what is happening for those who might not be aware of it but won't change the behaviour. The [configuring rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database) guide has more info in interactions between database.yml and DATABASE_URL if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

To connect with ActiveRecord without Rails (e.g. sinatra):

```
url = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  encoding: 'unicode',
  pool: 5,
  timeout: 5000,
  reconnect: true,
  adapter: url.scheme,
  host: url.host,
  database: url.path.sub(%r{^/}, ''),
  username: url.user,
  password: url.password
)
```